# Preloading Pivot Table In Schedule efficiency

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `User` model which has many `Postcode Sectors` . These sectors link up to a large dataset of `Properties` and the subset of properties from this large set are pulled into a smaller working table overnight for the total set of each user.

Given this dataset is quite large, would it be more efficient to also load a pivot table for a many to many relationship between `User` and `Property` when creating the job (which itself may be larger than the table being created due to duplicated sectors) or simply query the `Properties` table through these postcode sectors when needed?

The `Properties` table has **quite a large amount of columns** **(30+)** and has always been tough to query quickly in other applications.

Any tips of what would be advisable are appreciated.

Comment: You  could select only the fields you will use in the query.

Comment: Would this be faster than creating a pivot table and loading them in through eloquent? I guess only implementing both and testing speeds would only really show the best solution, but it could save hurt down the road trying to do it the "laravel" way only for it to impact performance too much